# "You ...... take photos here." What should go in the blank?

Tags: word-choice

> You ...... take photos here; there are many amazing places in this garden.

a. must
b. mustn't
c. needn't
d. shouldn't

I want to help I have an exam today and my teacher is tired and can't help. Can you please help me?

Comment: If I correctly assume which answer your teacher considers the correct or best one, then a better gap sentence would include the word "other": _You ...... take photos here; there are many __other__ amazing places in this garden_. A similar construction is: _You ...... tell her; she knows already._ So which of the four answers do you now think is the expected one?

Comment: The answer is (a). You must take photos because there are amazing places there. All other options are negative and it doesn't make sense to stop you from taking pictures if the place is nice.

Comment: @dubious. Yes, on reflection I think your interpretation may indeed be the expected answer. This is further evidence of the frequent problems associated with single decontextualised sentences in grammar questions.

Comment: "needn't" is maybe best if the sense is "don't take pictures", although I'd phrase it differently, as a negative imperative e.g. "Don't take pictures here" or "Don't bother taking any pictures here".

Comment: Agreed, it could also be (c), there is no need to take a picture here, as there will be plenty of other opportunities. Very poor question set by teacher.

Comment: @dubious shows correct reasoning. This is the hortative (in the semantic rather than syntactic sense) 'really must' sense of 'must', showing encouragement. 'You must try this delicious cherry pie, Jo!'

Comment: Note, this question isn't about grammar but checking that you understand the implied meaning.

Comment: The ambiguity could have been resolved by phrasing the question: "You ...... take photos here; this is the most amazing place in the garden."

Comment: I've voted to close.  The question is unanswerable. It is like "I like ...." a) cats,  b)dogs c) spiders d) apples.  All the options could be correct.

Answer (score 1):

The only word that makes sense is "must." The speaker says the garden has "many amazing places." That description would not justify saying that a photographer *mustn't*, *needn't* or *shouldn't* want to take photographs in the garden.

Comment: How about "you needn't take photos *here*, there are enough other amazing places to take photos"? Perhaps the speaker is trying to rush the photographer to a place they would rather be.

Comment: That could be, but without a reference to "other" places, as some have pointed out, that is not what is being said. The determining word is "this" -- there are many amazing places in *this* garden.

Comment: I don't believe it requires that word to carry that meaning (in conversations it would likely be hinted at by emphasizing the word "many"), but thanks for sharing your view. (And I noticed I *did* use the word 'other' in my example, so it apparently would come naturally :)